# Creating a dynamic timeline that only takes into account office hours

Tags: excel, date, datetime, excel-formula, excel-2010

relatively new to excel here.

### Pt.1 - Creating a dynamic weekday timeline based on hours

I'm trying to make a timeline based on the hours of each task, like so:

[image]

I know how to just add hours to a date&time, but there are a few other things I have to take into account:

- Days only run from 08:00 h to 16:00 h, any task that runs past 16:00 h on one day is continued on the next.
- Only counts weekdays, so it goes from Mon->Fri and Fri->Mon

The idea is that I can use this table for any project, and just knowing the time required for each task generates a timeline.

### Pt.2 - Adding a column for actual completed dates

To make it even more complicated, I want to add another column, where I can write in when I actually completed a task, that then updates the rest of the table, like this:

[image]

I've currently got some massive and admittedly disorganized formulas in the **Start** and **End** Columns, though I suspect its better off starting from scratch. They dont work all the time (don't skip weekends, count hours outside the 8am-16pm range), and they are as follows:

**Start:** `=IF(W9<>"", IF(TIME(HOUR(AA8), MINUTE(AA8), SECOND(AA8))<TIME(16,0,0),AA8,DATE(YEAR(AA8),MONTH(AA8),DAY(AA8))+1+TIME(8,0,0))+SUM(INT((WEEKDAY(AA8-{1,7})+DATE(YEAR(AA8),MONTH(AA8),DAY(AA8))+1+TIME(8,0,0)-AA8)/7)), "")=IF(W9<>"", IF(TIME(HOUR(AA8), MINUTE(AA8), SECOND(AA8))<TIME(16,0,0),AA8,DATE(YEAR(AA8),MONTH(AA8),DAY(AA8))+1+TIME(8,0,0))+SUM(INT((WEEKDAY(AA8-{1,7})+DATE(YEAR(AA8),MONTH(AA8),DAY(AA8))+1+TIME(8,0,0)-AA8)/7)), "")`

**End:** `=IF(AB10="", IF(W10<>"", IF(TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))+TIME(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1,0,0)>TIME(16,0,0), IF(Z10+TIME(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1, 0, 0)>TIME(16, 0, 0), IF(HOUR(DATE(YEAR(Z10),MONTH(Z10),DAY(Z10+1))+TIME(8,0,0)+ROUNDDOWN(((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8, 0)+TIME(((((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8)-ROUNDDOWN(((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8, 0))*8, 0, 0))=8, DATE(YEAR(Z10),MONTH(Z10),DAY(Z10+1))+TIME(8,0,0)+ROUNDDOWN(((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8, 0)+TIME(((((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8)-ROUNDDOWN(((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8, 0))*8, 0, 0)-(2/3), DATE(YEAR(Z10),MONTH(Z10),DAY(Z10+1))+TIME(8,0,0)+ROUNDDOWN(((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8, 0)+TIME(((((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8)-ROUNDDOWN(((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8, 0))*8, 0, 0)), Z10+TIME(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1, 0, 0)), Z10+TIME(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10), 0, 0))+SUM(INT((WEEKDAY(Z10-{1,7})+IF(TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))+TIME(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1,0,0)>TIME(16,0,0), IF(Z10+TIME(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1, 0, 0)>TIME(16, 0, 0), IF(HOUR(DATE(YEAR(Z10),MONTH(Z10),DAY(Z10+1))+TIME(8,0,0)+ROUNDDOWN(((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8, 0)+TIME(((((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8)-ROUNDDOWN(((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8, 0))*8, 0, 0))=8, DATE(YEAR(Z10),MONTH(Z10),DAY(Z10+1))+TIME(8,0,0)+ROUNDDOWN(((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8, 0)+TIME(((((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8)-ROUNDDOWN(((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8, 0))*8, 0, 0)-(2/3), DATE(YEAR(Z10),MONTH(Z10),DAY(Z10+1))+TIME(8,0,0)+ROUNDDOWN(((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8, 0)+TIME(((((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8)-ROUNDDOWN(((HOUR((TIME(HOUR(Z10),MINUTE(Z10),SECOND(Z10))))+IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1)-16)/8, 0))*8, 0, 0)), Z10+TIME(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10)+1, 0, 0)), Z10+TIME(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Concept", W10)), Y10/3, Y10), 0, 0))-Z10)/7)), ""), AB10+AC10)`

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that your the first row of your pictured table is in row 3 and the *End* column is column D, please paste the formula below to D3, but not before having made a few preparations.

1. Set up a named range `DayStart` and enter `=Time(8,0,0)` into its only cell.
2. Set up a named range `DayEnd` and enter `=Time(16,0,0)` into its only cell.
3. Set up a named range Holidays and enter the dates of non-working days other than Saturdays and Sundays.

These three ranges can be anywhere in the workbook provided their scope includes the worksheet on which the formula is pasted. The holidays will be considered as off-days. The work hours can be changed at any time.

```
=WORKDAY(C3,INT((((MOD(C3,1)-DayStart)+(B3/24))/(DayEnd-DayStart))),Holidays)+(MOD((((MOD(C3,1)-DayStart)+(B3/24))/(DayEnd-DayStart)),1)*(DayEnd-DayStart))+IF(ABS((((MOD(C3,1)-DayStart)+(B3/24))/(DayEnd-DayStart))-1)>(0.1^4),DayStart,(DayEnd-1))
```

Here are a few formulas copied form my development process.

```
=WORKDAY(C3,INT(J3),Holidays)+K3
[K3] =(MOD(J3,1)*(DayEnd-DayStart))+IF(ABS(J3-1)>(0.1^4),DayStart,(DayEnd-1))
[J3] =(I3/(DayEnd-DayStart))
[I3] =(G3+F3)
[G3] =(MOD(C3,1)-DayStart)
[F3] =(B3/24)
```

[B3] hold the number of hours, not as `Time` but as a plain integer (didn't try fractions) as in your pictured table.
[C3] promises to be a problem, at least in the format you seem to have.
I used a formula like `=DATE(2020,1,22)+TIME(8,0,0)` to ensure a proper date. The problem I foresee arises if you intend to use the current date in the table caption to define the date in column C.

FYI, I found the date format you used not convenient because I tested with up to 64 hours and several imaginary holidays. So, I needed a date format like `ddd, mmm dd, yyyy hh:mm`, to include the full date as well as the weekday.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and the through explanation. Will try out your solution later today and see how it goes.